# 2 caminhos diferentes na saída da compilação

Tags: visual-studio

Como posso fazer para que a saída da compilação seja em 2 lugares diferentes, teria como?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um evento de compilação que faça a cópia, algo assim:

```
Project Properties -> Build Events -> Post-build event command line
```

Pode colocar qualquer comando que o sistema operacional aceite. Por exemplo:

```
xcopy /y $(ProjectDir)arquivo.exe \OndeQuiser
```

[image: Post Event Build]

Comment: Queria colocar em uma pasta no disco C como ficaria o código?